# How to update each object of a LiveData list?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-room, android-livedata

I want to practice MVVM so I developed a simple Android app using Room, a DAO with LiveData, ViewModels.

There is one table, "Restaurants" which contains RestaurantEntities, that are displayed in a RecyclerView.
Here is the RestaurantListViewModel

```java
public class RestaurantListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<RestaurantEntity>> mRestaurants;

    public RestaurantListViewModel(@NonNull Application application, @NonNull SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = ((BasicApp) application).getRepository();
        mRestaurants = mRepository.getRestaurants();
    }

    /**
     * Expose the LiveData Restaurants query so the UI can observe it.
     */
    public LiveData<List<RestaurantEntity>> getRestaurants() {
        return mRestaurants;
    }

    public void updateRestaurants(List<RestaurantEntity> restaurants) {
        mRepository.updateRestaurants(restaurants);
    }
```

My goal is to trigger an update for each all Restaurants distances from the user, by doing so:

1. Iterating using for-each loop on each RestaurantEntity
2. Updating each `distance` attribute
3. Replacing the existing data

At which stage of the MVVM pattern should I do that?

If I trigger the update in the MainActivity:

```java
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mRestaurantListViewModel.getRestaurants().observe(this, restaurantEntities -> {
            List<Restaurant> updatedEntities = updateRestaurantsDistances(restaurantEntities, myLocation);  // some computation in a background thread
            mRestaurantListViewModel.updateRestaurants(updatedEntities);                                    // calls the repository and the DAO
        });
    }
});
```

The observer is triggered by the observer itself on the update event, causing an infinite loop. I can't figure out a way that does not look like a "hack" to solve that issue, like the following, that crashes in a NullPointerException if the async `currentEntities = restaurantEntities` had not been executed before triggering the onclick:

```java
List<Restaurant> currentEntities = null;
mRestaurantListViewModel.getRestaurants().observe(this, restaurantEntities -> currentEntities = restaurantEntities);

Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        List<Restaurant> updatedEntities = updateRestaurantsDistances(currentEntities , myLocation);
        mRestaurantListViewModel.updateRestaurants(updatedEntities);
    }
});
```

1. What would be a better, working architecture or approach for this?
2. Is there a more advanced BasicSample (similar to this) to practice on?

Comment: 1. Register once, not each time onClick is triggered.
2. Smth is wrong with the logic - looks like updateRestaurantsDistances() is in activity and is should be rather in view-model.
3. How do you want to display this list?

If you want to start update with button clicked, then you should only call appropriate method in view model that will do the update. When update is done you should post the value (list) on LiveData (use MutableLiveData for that). Then in your observer you should notify your list adapter about the change.

Comment: 1. As I did with the second example?
2. The onClick should directly call `mRestaurantListViewModel.updateRestaurantsDistances(currentEntities , myLocation)`, which would then propagate the updated list to the DAO if I understood. There are two issues I am encountering with this:
- if the currentEntities is null, the app crashes, how to wait for the observe to be completed first?
- I have to run the update in a background thread, to do not lock the UI
3. The list is databound to a recyclerview on activity creation, displaying default values if they have not been updated.

Comment: I managed to make it work, using a dirty infinite loop in a background thread:
`while (currentEntities == null) { }
mRestaurantListViewModel.updateRestaurants(updatedEntities);`
Is there something I didn't get, to wait for an observer or to synchronize?